# A small issue with the comparison of a series and its integrals.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

So basically, in my textbook I am given this way of majoring and minoring a series"

Let $f: [0,+\infty)$, strictly decreasing on the interval.

Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then we have:

$$\int^{k+1}_{k}f(t)dt \: \leq \: f(k) \:\leq \:\int^{k}_{k-1}f(t)dt$$

So far so good.

Now, I am given this:

$$f(0) + \int^{n+1}_{1}f(t)dt \: \leq \sum^{n}_{k=0}f(k) \: \leq \: \:f(0)+\int^{n}_{0}f(t)dt $$

What I fail to understand is the reason the $f(0)$ are added on both sides

Comment: The first inequalities are valid only for $k>0$, while the sum includes $f(0)$.

Comment: On the left hand side, you could just as well write $\int_0^{n+1} f(t)\,dt$. On the right hand side, you use $\int_0^n f(t)\,dt \geqslant \sum_{k = 1}^n f(k)$, and therefore you need to add $f(0)$ there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we subtract $f(0)$ from all sides, then

$$\int_1^{n+1}f(t)\ dt\le\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)\le\int_0^nf(t)\ dt$$

Note that we can't just extend the integrals further since $f(t)$ is undefined when $t<0$.  Instead, we just add it onto all sides.